# How to add a json text file (x.json) into an existing mp4 file (x.mp4)

Tags: json, metadata, mp4box

I’m trying to add a json text file (x.json) into an existing mp4 file (x.mp4) using mp4box. Seemed simple enough but I’m getting nowhere.

`MP4Box -add x.mp4 -set-meta box:tk=0 -add-item x.json:tk=0:name=metadata:mime=text/plain fusion.mp4`

Answer (score 1):

GPAC maintainer here. First, for other readers, the online documentation is [here](https://github.com/gpac/gpac/issues). An example is [there](https://github.com/gpac/testsuite/blob/174f0812e5271f22bc3c872cb1ecf43e04551c83/scripts/item.sh#L20).

You need two command-lines to achieve this:

```
MP4Box -set-meta box:tk=0 input.mp4 -out output.mp4
MP4Box -add-item x.json:tk=0:name=metadata:mime=text/plain output.mp4
```

In general, or if you wish to continue the discussion, please file an issue on [our official tracker](https://github.com/gpac/testsuite/blob/174f0812e5271f22bc3c872cb1ecf43e04551c83/scripts/item.sh#L20). There is not only me but also all our community to help you.

Comment: I’m sorry but the above code does not integrate the x.json into the file in any way. Neither in the moov atom nor as a layer.

Comment: Ok I think I know what's wrong. Does it work if you remove the :tk=0 from the second command-line?

Comment: Nope. Didn’t add anything.

Comment: I suggest that you open an issue [here](https://github.com/gpac/gpac/issues). Please refer to this thread, provide all the requested information when submitting the issue. In particular we provide a way to upload your content anonymously, please provide yours. Thanks

Comment: Was this ever solved? @R.Bouqueau

Comment: I couldn't reproduce because not enough information was provided. If you have the issue, please [file an issue on the GPAC open-source bug tracker](https://github.com/gpac/gpac/issues/new/).